# Unable to parse JSON data into Listview

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing

im trying to parse data from SQL Database into Listview.
My PHP script is working because if i run it in the browser i get the content.
If im trying to get the data from my SQL Databse into the listview my app shows nothing.
Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class Locations extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<productforloc> arrayList;
ListView lv;
private String TAG = Locations.class.getSimpleName();
private TextView addressField; //Add a new TextView to your activity_main to display the address
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
int i = 1;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String name;



// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "Mylink";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String cityname = i.getExtras().getString("cityname");
    TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ort);
    city.setText(cityname);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Locations.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);





runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ReadJSON().execute(url);
        }
    });

final ImageButton filteropen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
    filteropen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ImageButton filterclose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
            filterclose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filteropen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
final ImageButton filterclose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.zuklappen);
    filterclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout filter = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.filterloc);
            filter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageButton filteropen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aufklaupen);
            filteropen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            filterclose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}



class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {






    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        try{
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("contacts");

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
                JSONObject po = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(new productforloc(
                        po.getString("imageurl"),
                        po.getString("name"),
                        po.getString("street"),
                        po.getString("postalcode"),
                        po.getString("musicstyle"),
                        po.getString("musicsecond"),
                        po.getString("entry"),
                        po.getString("opening"),
                        po.getString("agegroup"),
                        po.getString("urlbtn"),
                        po.getString("Fsk"),
                        po.getString("city"),
                        po.getString("bg")

                ));

            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final CustomListAdapterforloc adapter = new CustomListAdapterforloc(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.model,arrayList);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }

    }




private String readURL(String url){
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();


   try{
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = uri.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null){
            content.append(line+"\n");


        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content.toString();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    productforloc pForloc = arrayList.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,DetailActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name",pForloc.getName());
    intent.putExtra("imageurl",pForloc.getImage());
    intent.putExtra("street",pForloc.getStreet());
    intent.putExtra("postalcode",pForloc.getPostalcode());
    intent.putExtra("entry",pForloc.getEntry());
    intent.putExtra("agegroup",pForloc.getAgegroup());
    intent.putExtra("opening",pForloc.getOpening());
    intent.putExtra("urlbtn",pForloc.getUrlbtn());
    intent.putExtra("Fsk",pForloc.getFsk());
    intent.putExtra("city",pForloc.getCity());
    intent.putExtra("musicstyle",pForloc.getMusicstyle());
    intent.putExtra("musicsecond",pForloc.getMusicsecond());
    intent.putExtra("bg",pForloc.getBg());
    startActivity(intent);


}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call

 }



 */
```

}

and here is my Customlistadapter Activity:

```
public class CustomListAdapterforloc extends ArrayAdapter<productforloc>{

ArrayList<productforloc> products;
Context context;
int resource;
public CustomListAdapterforloc(Context context, int resource, List<productforloc> products) {

    super(context, resource, products);
    this.products = (ArrayList<productforloc>) products;
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView== null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.model,null,true);
    }
    productforloc product = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
    Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(imageView);
    TextView txtName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namelist);
    txtName.setText(product.getName());



    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: This is not PHP...

Comment: Try to make a [mcve]. You do not need an AsyncTask or JSON to know if a ListView is able to show any data. You could have a layout problem in your XML

Comment: do some debugging. Check if you connect to the server, if you receive the data, if the data is proper json, if you get your content in the arraylist, if the listview is there, if it is visible, if the adapter's `getView` is called and has the right data.

Comment: @Alex Howansky yes i didnt share my PHP script because if i run it on the Browser i get the json

Comment: i got the error message:

Comment: error parsing data value of type org json jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using this code in my MAinActivity:

```
public class Locations extends AppCompatActivity {
private String TAG = Locations.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://partypeople.bplaced.net/loli.php";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Locations.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String gender = c.getString("gender");



                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("email", email);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**3
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Locations.this, contactList,
                R.layout.model, new String[]{"name", "email",
                "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.namelist,
               });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

and used in my CustomlistadapterActivity:

```
public class HttpHandler {


private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpHandler() {
}

public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Thanks for your input

Answer (score -2):

Override **getCount** method into adapter class.

Comment: Not necessary when extending ArrayAdapter unless you have a different list passed into the constructor.